# Using skimage.color.gray2rgb produces a wrong output image

Tags: image-processing, grayscale

Hello I was just trying to make a code to set up a grayscale image as a three channel image format and then display it. I am using skimage.color  function gray2rgb which does change the shape of the mono scale image matrix. However when wanting to plot the result of that conversion I get an unexpected image as output.

Also I am having a hard time to create an empty 3 channel image to fill it with whatever monoscale information I want. Apparently because of nature of image as uint16 there is some problem with matplotlib

I have tried np.vstack, skimage.color.gray2rgb. All of them produce the same output.
I have tried using np.uint8 to convert from 65535 max pixel value to 255 but it is not working. It seems that division works

```
from skimage.io import imread, imshow
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import os
import numpy as np
img = imread('516.jpg')
img_uint8 = np.uint8(img)
from skimage.color import gray2rgb
from skimage import img_as_float
img_rgb = gray2rgb(img_uint8, alpha=None)
print(img_rgb.shape)
plt.imshow(img_rgb)
```

Image shown is not what it would be expected!!!!

I would expect an image similar to original but probably with a different color since it should be the same image in all 3 channels.
I think the problem is with np.uint8 for my image. I tested with cameraman image and had no problem

Comment: You need to divide by 256 before converting to uint8.

Comment: Since it is my first contribution you can download the image from my google drive: https://drive.google.com/file/d/124CNKFp1RSbjRkPfj64YTFg76A0SCIp1/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why but it seems that using **img_as_ubyte** makes possible to copy the gray image in the three channels and be able to display an image similar to original

```
from skimage import img_as_ubyte
i = imread('516.jpg')
i_8 = img_as_ubyte(i)
imshow(i_8)
print(i_8)
i_8rgb = gray2rgb(i_8)
plt.imshow(i_8rgb, cmap='gray')
```

Don't know why yet np.uint8 produces a result altered. Somehow also using openCV as a read seems to always put image in a uint8 range, which could be handy.
I wait for your comments

[Original Image used for testing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eE4XM.png)
[This is what np.uint8 seems to be producing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DmPdR.jpg)